# Hide fixed positioned div (parallax) under other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to set up a parallax effect div inside a section of the page, trouble is that I'm having a hard time positioning so it shows up only on the parent section (id 'foo' on the code below) of the page. How can I make that happen?

HTML

```
<section>
  <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>

</section>

<article id="foo">
    <div id="parallax"></div>
</article>

<section>
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>

</section>
```

CSS

```
#parallax {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-220-129-8.jpg') transparent no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    z-index: 20;
    right: -73%;
   position: fixed;
}

article {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

section {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 1%;
}
```

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

function parallax(){

if($(window).scrollTop() < $('#foo').offset().top){

var parallaxLayer = document.getElementById('parallax');
parallaxLayer.style.top = ((window.pageYOffset / 4) - 400)+'px';
}else{

}

}
window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax, false);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ksahn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fdg9du90/show/

**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/fdg9du90/

```
var w=$(window), bg = $('.bg');

w.scroll(function(e){
   bg.css('top','-'+w.scrollTop()*.5+'px');
});
```

**Explanation:**

Background image/div is set as fixed, jquery is used to make things easier by that i mean easily attaching event, getting data fast and in right form, etc. On scroll event at windows the data amount window has scrolled is taken and halfed and then background div is moved by that amount.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want to did ?
I had overwrite your code in codepen.
Hope it will help.
***codepen.io/jaminpie/pen/Lnjtc***

Comment: Not quite. I want the div to have that position (divs over and below overlapping) but I want it to scroll in a different speed than the window (parallax effect).